# Huge gaps between my tile textures in Godot

Tags: tilemap, godot

[image: Gaps between tiles in a grid]

The texture itself doesn't have any gaps in it. I don't know where these gaps are coming from. Someone suggested that I check if the sprite sheet's cell size and padding are correct. When I checked I couldn't see any such option in Godot. Can someone kindly explain?

Comment: Are these really gaps or just the visual indicators for a cell size?

Comment: Knowing more about *how* you are trying to use the spritesheet would help - some of the Godot UI is context dependent and changes based on what sort of Node you're working with. Are you trying to use a [Tileset node](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/2d/using_tilesets.html), or something else? It might not matter, but specifying the version of Godot may also make a difference.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got this result... Do you have a single file that Godot split, or are these multiple files? Anyway, it seems to me that the size configured in the tilemap is larger than the tiles, and setting it to match the tiles would solve it. Aside form that, do you want to scale the tiles? in that case, I think afterwards you can scale the tilemp as a whole.